# C# reference Error while setting value using GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty for existing Property

Tags: c#, properties, async-await, gettype

I have a relatively simple console app (framework) which has a tightly coupled classes with properties and my main triggers an async task. These are my property classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;                      //for HTTP client
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;               //for Async Request/Response
using Newtonsoft.Json;                      //for JSON properties

namespace PSD2
{
    [Serializable]
    public class PS
    {
        public System.Uri BaseURL { get; set; } = new System.Uri("http://192.999.999.999:8888/some/url/here/");
        public ConsHeaders Headers { get; set; }
        public ConsBody Body { get; set; }
        public consAttributes Attributes { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public partial class ConsHeaders
    {
        [JsonProperty("Core-ID")]
        public string corID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("PS-Token")]
        public string PS_Token { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Req-ID")]
        public string reqID { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public partial class consAttributes
    {
        [JsonProperty("consId")]
        public string consId { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [JsonProperty("consStatus")]
        public string consStatus { get; set; } = String.Empty;

        [JsonProperty("userName")]
        public string userName { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    };

    [Serializable]
    public partial class consBody
    {
        [JsonProperty("access")]
        public AccessHeaders access { get; internal set; }

        [JsonProperty("combinedServiceIndicator")]
        public Boolean CombinedServiceIndicator { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonProperty("frequencyPerDay")]
        public int FrequencyPerDay { get; set; } = 4;

        [JsonProperty("recurringIndicator")]
        public Boolean RecurringIndicator { get; set; } = false;

        [JsonProperty("validUntil")]
        public string ValidUntil { get; set; } = "9999-12-31";
    }
...
```

Now, my Program class creates an object and in Main I call a class called testing who has my logic behind, nothing more than populating the object properties with values, and calls a Task asycn which is also present inside. Code continues from above as:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static PS cnsnt = new PS();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Testing test = new Testing();
            test.createCONS();
        }

        public class Testing
        {
            public void createCONS()
            {
                try
                {
                    cnsnt.Headers = new ConsHeaders
                    {
                        corID = "Something",
                        reqID = "AnotherThing",
                        PS_Token = "myTokenValue"
                    };

                    cnsnt.Body = new ConsBody
                    {
                        access = new AccessHeaders
                        {
                            AllPsd2 = "allAccounts",
                            AvailableAccounts = "YES"
                        },
                        CombinedServiceIndicator = false,
                        FrequencyPerDay = 10,
                        ValidUntil = "2020-12-31"
                    };

                    cnsnt.Attributes = new consAttributes
                    {
                        consId = "",
                        _links_self_href = "",
                        consStatus = "",
                        status_href = "",
                        userName = ""
                    };
                }
                catch (System.Exception e)
                {
                    throw new System.Exception("Error - Aborting..");
                }

                myConsAsync(cnsnt.BaseURL, cnsnt, HttpMethod.Post).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }


            public async static Task myConsAsync(Uri HTTPaddress, PS ConSent, HttpMethod httpMethod)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    System.Text.UTF8Encoding utf8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true);

                    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, HTTPaddress))
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = HTTPaddress;
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                        //...
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Core-ID", ConSent.Headers.corID);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Req-ID", ConSent.Headers.reqID);
                        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PS-Token", ConSent.Headers.PS_Token);
                        //...

                        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ConSent, Formatting.Indented), utf8, "application/json");

                        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
                        {
                            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                            Int32 code = (Int32)response.StatusCode;
                            string responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result.ToString();

                            try
                            {
                                if (responseBody.Contains("consId"))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        string responseValues = JSONtoKeyValue(responseBody);

                                        var dict = responseValues.Split('|')
                                            .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                                            .Where(x => x.Length > 1 
                                                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[0].Trim())
                                                && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x[1].Trim()))
                                            .ToDictionary(x => x[0].Trim(), x => x[1].Trim());

                                        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in dict)
                                        {
                                            if (entry.Value == null)
                                            {
                                                dict.Remove(entry.Key);
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                string key = entry.Key;
                                                string value = entry.Value;


                                                try
                                                {
                                                    if (cnsnt.Attributes.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key) != null)
                                                    {
                                                        // ---> ERROR:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
                                                        cnsnt.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                catch (System.Exception e)
                                                {
                                                    Console.WriteLine("Failed during processing Property: " + e.Message);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        Console.ReadLine();
                                    }
                                    catch (System.Exception e)
                                    {
                                        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + "\r\n" + e.Message);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    throw new System.Exception("Fatal error reading response body for the consent Id. Aborting..");
                                };
                            }
                            catch (System.Exception e)
                            {
                                Environment.Exit(13);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    //whatever, Console.WriteLine("Error in " + e.TargetSite + "\r\n" + e.Message + "\r\n" + e.Data);
                }
                //return 
            }

            // this works as intended.. included just for completion
            public static string JSONtoKeyValue(string pString)
            {
                pString.Trim();
                if (pString == null)
                {
                    return "";
                }
                else
                {
                    pString = pString.Replace("\r\n", "|").Replace(":", "=").Replace("\"", "").Replace("{", "").Replace("}", "").Replace(",", "");
                    int j = 0, inputlen = pString.Length;
                    char[] newarr = new char[inputlen];
                    for (int i = 0; i < inputlen; ++i)
                    {
                        char tmp = pString[i];
                        if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(tmp))
                        {
                            newarr[j] = tmp; ++j;
                        }
                    }
                    return new String(newarr, 0, j).Replace("||", "|").Replace("||", "|").Replace("=|", "_").Trim('|');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice in the Task that I want to read a string separated with pipes (a small method does the work nicely) and I try to see if I have this property in my object, and if yes, to populate the value.

However, in line 
ConSent.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value);
I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I struggle on this one, could someone help me?

Comment: The usual approach is to split that line into multiple lines and check each intermittent step individually. You should be able to diagnose rather quickly which step is misbehaving. My guess is that the property does not exist for the key.

Comment: Note: Maybe is a combination of calling `ConSent.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value);` with correct arguments, i.e. the cnsnt object maybe wrong, in combination with some missing ref or initialization? But I have initialized the object passed it to the Task and actually works, I receive response as expected. But I can't populate my properties with the values.. (there is a reason I am not referencing directly to the properties, is a test program that reads the response and expects to find the names in the JSON keys as properties).

Comment: @germi: the error is produced exactly on `ConSent.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value);` - the catch returns it. I don't know what has to be done for the `ConSent.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value);` to work correctly..

Comment: NOTE: The `JSONtoKeyValue` has been included only for completion. Feel free to delete it and put a string instead, or leave it and try with a string like `"_links_self_href"="hello gents"|"status_href"="thank you"` - remember, the keys have to be present in consAttributes class on top. Actually this string should work just fine.. but the error persists.. even for existing properties (tested).

Comment: Add either the safe navigation operator or split out the method chain into individual statements to debug which part of it is failing. Its generally a good idea to use the safe navigation operator when chaining requests like this where any of them might return null and cause an exception.

Comment: @Josh, Hi, thank you so much, actually just did it, but still can't understand the nature of the error. So, since with the line `if (responseBody.Contains("consId"))` I verify that this key is in the `responseBody` string, I do `cnsnt.Attributes.XXX = responseBody.Substring(responseBody.IndexOf("consentId") + 13, 36);` which is actually only to verify that the `cnsnt` is there and that I can write to the property `XXX` - and I can. So, why just a few lines below the `GetType().GetTypeInfo()..` doesn't work ? I am really crying here..

Comment: @Josh May I ask, is the `GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value)` correct? I mean, the `cnsnt` part. Do you have any example setting a value to a property like this? Just thought to ask..

Answer (score 1):

You have made a simple mistake.

You check for

```
(cnsnt.Attributes.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key) != null)
```

But then you assign with

```
ConSent.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value)
```

Just replace it with,

```
cnsnt.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key).SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value).
```

Note its **cnsnt**. Not **ConSent**.

and you'll be fine. Happy reflecting!

edit:

saw your edit, same thing.

cnsnt.**Attributes**.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key)
                                                        cnsnt.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key)

you are basically checking on a different bject if it has a property and then you try to set it on another.

Suggestion.

Why not go:

```
var keyProperty = cnsnt.Attributes.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredProperty(key);
if(keyProperty != null)
{
    keyProperty.SetValue(cnsnt, entry.Value);
}
```

this way it will not fail, ever.

Comment: Thank you, let me check if it is a typo though.. apologies..Yeap, sorry, typo - I was playing around trying to sort it out.. Same error..

Comment: added an edit. hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, didn't solve the problem, but I think I got a better sense: seems that cnsnt has nested class, and although I added constructors to relevant classes, the SetValue can't really found its way in.. or something like that ..